# Phalcon Model Manager

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to create a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM course
where course.id IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT(course_id)
FROM course_timing tim
WHERE tim.date >= CURDATE()
    )
```

I have set the model manger

```
 $di->set('modelsManager', function() {
      return new Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager();
    });
```

But when i try to use

```
       $phql = "SELECT * FROM CourseTiming";
       $rows = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

I am getting

**Model 'CourseTiming' could not be loaded**

Or is there any way to run the above query using Model::find etc

Comment: Do you have CourseTiming Model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHQL uses models classes (not db tables names) in the query, so you should create CourseTiming model to access your db table via PHQL:

```
<?php

class CourseTiming extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;
    ....

    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'course_timing'; // name of db table here
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register models directory in the Phalcon loader:

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(array(
    'pathToModelsDir',
    ...
));
$loader->register();
```

Another way is to access db via Phalcon PDO (you don't need to create CourseTiming model in this case).

index.php:

```
$di->setShared('db', function() {
    $db = new Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'dbname'   => 'my_db',
    ));
    return $db;
});
```

controller:

```
$records = $this->db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM course_timing", Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I had every thing loaded and working. Later i realize if i use full path like \Ilm\Frontend\Models\CourseTiming it worked. But still if i just use CourseTiming it give the above error.

Comment: Secondly can you please explain the difference between setShared and set. and also is there any disadventage to get the data directlly with out using PHQL. Thankyou

Comment: If you use model then PHalcon will build PHQL for you. Second thing is that you used namespaced model so in that case you must provide namespace in PHQL - so in this case using `Model::find()` or `Model::query()->andWhere()->...->execute()` requires less writing.

Comment: @User707 `set()` - new instance will be created and returned every time you access service in DI. `setShared()` - just one instance will be created  during first DI request and another requests will receive this instance (something like singleton).